# How to easily add syntax highlighting for custom DSL into Vim

Tags: vim

I am wondering how to conveniently add a custom DSL syntax highlighting into VIM. Is there any good tutorial on this topic anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vim wiki on wikia has a nice tutorial about the creation of syntax files

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_your_own_syntax_files

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure there are tutorials available but the basic steps are :

- Read `:help syntax` from Vim, all of it, to understand how syntax highlighting work in Vim
- Have a look at existing syntax file in $VIMRUNTIME\syntax, identifying the language closest of what you want. By adapting an existing file, you won't have to rewrite everything from scratch.
- Create your own syntax file (+ file type) this will probably takes you some time.
- Add the following line to your .vimrc to use your newly created file type:
  `au BufNewFile,BufRead *.newtype set filetype=newtype`

Alternatively, if your language is somewhat popular, there is a good chance that someone else has already written a `language.vim`. If it is not available from [vim.org](http://www.vim.org) you can search on github.